# Google Appengine: User.equals throws NullPointerException

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a frustrating issue that my app on Google Appengine throws NullPointerException like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.api.users.User.equals(User.java:143)
```

My code looks like:

```
if (excludeUser.equals(someEntity.getProperty("user")))
```

The user property in the entity was another User object previously stored in the datastore. Even if I change the code to something like the following, it does not raise the exception:

```
if (excludeUser.equals(null))
```

So I guess it's some internal logic in User.equals causes the problem, or some other tricky thing when storing the user object into the datastore?

In addition, the logic works well in development environment. The problem only happens on GAE.

I'm using the Google Accounts API, not the Federated login. I tried them both. The same result. Any clue is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things turn out to be special case from the UserService.getUser(). No idea why it returns a not-null user, with the following content:

```
authDomain:https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud, 
email:, 
federatedId:https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=....., 
nickname:, 
userId:
```

Invoking .equals method on such object with other normal User objects results the NullPointerException. Guess this is somekind of the Federated Login weirdo?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `someEntity` object .. it is likely that it is a null object due to which you are seeing that error. I suggest stepping through your code and verifying if that object is not null.

Comment: The object is not null. First it can be viewed from Datastore viewer in admin console. Second I change that value explicitly to null, and no such exception (It means User.equals(null) works fine). Third, it works fine with development environment...This problem is really confusing :(...

Comment: most likely excludeUser is null.  If the excludeUser object isfetched from the datastore, probably something about the data in the production datastore is different enough from your dev_appserver version to cause it to crash.

Comment: excludeUser is not null here. The null pointer exception is thrown from inside the User.equals() method itself. So the caller reference (the excludeUser) should not be null.

Comment: I recall something suspicious... prevously the app worked, but I changed the auth method from Google Accounts API to Federated Login in admin console, and redeployed the app several times, then this error occurs...maybe there's some relationship? Not so sure...

Comment: Things turn out to be special case from the UserService.getCurrentUser(). No idea why it returns a not-null user, with the following content with my browser sometime: 

    authDomain:https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud, 
    email:, 
    federatedId:https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=....., 
    nickname:, 
    userId:

Invoking .equals method on such object with other normal User objects results the NullPointerException. Guess this is somekind of the Federated Login weirdo?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in User.equals().

The call to `federatedIdentity.equals` [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/users/User.java#143) should be flipped.

The line should read `return federatedIdentity.equals(user.federatedIdentity)`.

I've reported this to Google.